# Image banner not taking correct width in outlook

Tags: html, css, email, email-client

My image advert banner is meant to take a max-width of 600px. When i test the email template in litmus, in outlook 2013, it stretches more than 600px causing it to look wider than rest of the email template which is 600px wide. Anyone know any fixes around this please?

Thanks

Comment: it is cut exactly to 600px, but when i view it, the width is 665px only in outlook 2013, the other email clients are okay. My email is responsive.

Comment: Show some HTML, otherwise it'll be all pure guessing

Comment: how do i paste the code on here

Comment: you simply paste the code right into your question after clicking `edit` link. after you paste the code, select it and format it properly using the `{}` button.